# Gradle Script to make a REST call (POST, GET)

Tags: java, rest, groovy, gradle, build

I am trying `gradle` for the first time.

I want to call some REST API in a gradle script and validate some responses I receive back.

Current system configurations include `Java 1.7`, `Gradle 2.4` running on a `Oracle Linux 6.5`

**My `REST API` :**

API => POST localhost/Assign

JSON Input :

```
{"user":"dummyuser"}
```

JSON Output :

```
{
  "jobMessageDetails": "dummyuser has been assigned to dummymachine",
  "jobStatusDetails": "Success",
  "jobType": "assign",
  "machineName": "dummymachine",
  "time": "2015/6/8 @ 14:47:42",
  "userName": "dummyuser"
}
```

I am able to test my `APIs` using `POSTMAN` from another machine. I do it like this : `POST` `hostname??:5500/Assign` `JSON_INPUT` using `POSTMAN`. They work correctly.

**What I want to do :**

- I want to call this `API` from a `Gradle` script.
- I want to parse the JSON_OUTPUT I receive.
- I want to read and print the `"jobStatusDetails"` & `"machineName"` from the response I receive.

---

**PS :** I am very new to Gradle, **I would appreciate a full working code**.

I have looked at the following links - [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24058926/gradle-script-to-call-a-rest-web-service-without-any-3rd-party-plugins-any-poin) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382845/how-to-package-rest-client-code-via-gradle-for-multi-project-usage). None of them helped me.

Comment: Why not test your service in test classes, rather than in a build task?

Comment: this rest api is to run integration tests by bringing up many services simultaneously. So I need this to happen in a gradle script

Comment: Sorry, looks like the mods agree with you. I take back my DV and CV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `URLConnection` API.

Post method example:

```
task demo {
    doLast {
        def body = [user: "dummyUser"]
        def req = new URL('https://hostname/Assign').openConnection()
        req.setRequestMethod("POST")
        req.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
        req.setDoOutput(true)
        req.getOutputStream().write(JsonOutput.toJson(body).getBytes("UTF-8"))
        logger.quiet "Status code: ${req.getResponseCode()}" // HTTP request done on first read
        def resp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(req.getInputStream().getText())
        logger.quiet "Response: ${resp}"
    }
}
```

For parsing you can use `JsonSlurper`